# Making WebRTC work in IE/safari

Tags: javascript, webrtc

so i am making a site that takes advantage of the WebRTC(webcam snapshots). 
ive been searching for hours, but didnt find a solution that didnt require a third party app install on the windows/OS X installation.

have any of your solved this problem?

Comment: IE and Safari don't yet support WebRTC, there's no way around that, and no way to really polyfill it.

Comment: damn, so how do you get around this? fallback to flash?

Comment: I don't know, real time communication with audio, video, files etc. opens the browser up to brand new things and features, it's not easy to recreate that in a browser that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see IE/Safari does not support WebRTC: http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc or http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/

The only way that you can do it is through a 3rd party plugin, like Skylink or Temasys. But you'll also need something like a polyfill on your JS. In the end, Flash is also another 3rd party plugin.

It seems that Edge has limited support and Safari could get very soon WebRTC support.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, things are about to change.

**Safari**

Apple announced support for WebRTC in Safari 11.

You can download the latest beta version of Safari 11 at the following link:
(You need to sign in with your Apple ID) https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

**Microsoft Edge**

Edge supports webRTC with the help of [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter).

Data channels are not yet supported.

According to Microsoft's [roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/rtcdatachannels/?filter=f3f0000bf&search=rtc&q=data%20channels), ORTC Data channels are "Under consideration".

> Roadmap Priority: Low — We are still evaluating this technology. There
>   may be significant spec stabilization, foundational work, or
>   additional community input required before we can begin development.

**Internet explorer**

As @adrian-ber said, you'll need a 3rd party plugin.